# DeadSystemException causing Google Pixel power cycling?

Tags: system-error, google-pixel

I am getting this error when my phone is power cycling randomly without my control. See below for previous error logs.

```
06-09 11:47:24.470 1379-1379/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.android.phone, PID: 1379
                                                 DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
```

**Back story:**

I bought a Google Pixel online recently, and I've had an issue with it power cycling randomly.

I've followed numerous online help and suggestions from sites such as [here](https://thedroidguy.com/2018/05/fix-google-pixel-keeps-restarting-troubleshooting-guide-potential-solution-1069479). Here's my experience

- The phone will operate normally for a week or so, then go into waves of power cycling very frequently
- Safe mode stops the power cycling
- A factory reset will cease the power cycling, I've done this once and assumed it had fixed it, but the issue has returned today.

I've done some android app development before so I booted up android studio to see if the debug logs could reveal the cause of this issue.

[Here's the logcat debug logs pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2bM1diih).